# Java class to calculate shortest and longest side of a triangle

Tags: java, class, methods, boolean

I've been working on my assignment all day and am stuck at just one part. I am pretty good at searching the internet and finding answers and have checked here as well. I still can't seem to figure out what is going on.

For the assignment we need to write a class with methods that will test a triangle. I am struggling with understanding classes, but have been able to get most of the code to work. The only issue I have now is with the `is_equilibrium();` method. When running with the program provided with the assignment, the equilibrium method will return true every time.

problem code:

```
public boolean is_equilateral()
{
    if(longest == shortest)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I change it to:

```
public boolean is_equilateral()
{
    if(side1 == side2 && side2 == side3&& side3 == side1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I the code works fine and will return the true or false values.

I hope I am asking everything right, I am still trying to learn java so please bear with me! Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any debugging performed on this code.  Please [edit] your question to show us what your debugging has uncovered, as well as a specific question about a specific line of code.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Your comment mentions is_equilibrium() but the code is is_equilateral(). Its pretty clear what you meant, but be careful with those typos!

Comment: Not nearly enough code here. What is longest and shortest? Where are they defined and manipulated? We can't tell anything from just this.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code from what we can see so there must be something wrong with where you're assigning longest and shortest.